# Always get “Cannot parse non Measurement Protocol hits”

Tags: google-analytics

I have a little Python program that other people use and I would like to offer opt-in telemetry such that can get an idea of the usage patterns. Google Analytics 4 with the Measurement Protocol seems to be the thing that I want to use. I have created a new *property* and a new *data* stream.

I have tried to validate the request and set it to `www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-LQDLGRLGZS&api_secret=JXGZ_CyvTt29ucNi9y0DkA` via post and send this JSON payload:

```js
{
    "app_instance_id": "MyAppId",
    "client_id": "TestClient.xx",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "login",
            "params": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The response that I get is this:

```js
{
    "validationMessages": [
        {
            "description": "Cannot parse non Measurement Protocol hits.",
            "validationCode": "INTERNAL_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

I seem to be doing exactly what they do in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag) or [tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase_mp#4). I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know, what is missing. What do I have to do in order to successfully validate the request?

Comment: Try to build the request with the GA4 event builder:
https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `/debug` part in the URL. In the example you followed it is not present so it is not quite exactly the same.

Comment: When I tried that yesterday, I got a permission error. I'll check whether I missed to enable some permissions.

Comment: Ok, this is another kind of error

Answer (score 1):

we just came across the same issue and the solution for us was to put https:// in front of the URL. Hope this helps.